# How can I set the route parameter name using a variable in Twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, silex

I am trying to use the `url` Twig function with Silex to generate a route, but when I use the variable name that I have passed to the template it generates a warning that I have not supplied the parameter.

This is the array I am passing to the template:

```
   [
     "total_pages" => $pages,
     "current_page" => $page,
     "route_name" => "gallery_album",
     "route_parameter" => "groupname",
     "route_value" => $groupname
   ]
```

And in the template I am trying to use:

```
{{ url(route_name, {route_parameter: route_value, 'page': page} ) }}
```

(The page variable value is worked out in the template)

This is part of a pagination template that I am building so I need the parameter to be a variable so it can be applied to different pages.  This is the error I get when I run this:

[image]

I feel this is something that is very simple, I am just missing something fundamental.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It thinks that `route_parameter` is a string key name and not a variable:

You can do for example:

```
{% set params = {'page': page, (route_parameter): route_value } %}
{{ url(route_name, params) }}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but it did not work.  I now get the error `Unexpected token "operator" of value "=" ("end of statement block" expected) in "pagination" ` for the `do` function.  (I am using Twig version 1.25.0)

Comment: @RussellSeymour I realized there's actually an easier way to do this with just `(var): val` syntax. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{{ app->path}}` or `{{ app->url }}`
if you using `Silex\Application\UrlGeneratorTrait` in you Application class

or alternative using this

```
{{ app.url_generator.generate('homepage') }}
```